# Why my own suid-ed program still holds the original uid?

Tags: c, linux, permissions, suid

I'm using the following program, and I've suid-ed it (by running `chown root XXX; chmod 4755 XXX` as root), but the output is still `ruid 1000, euid 1000, suid 1000`, shouldn't effect uid be zero here?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        uid_t ruid, euid, suid;
        if (! getresuid (&ruid, &euid, &suid))
                printf ("ruid %d, euid %d, suid %d\n", ruid, euid, suid);
        else
                perror ("getresuid");

        return 0;
}
```

Output of ls -l:

`-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 9.7K May  1 11:36 test*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the `mount` command output, your file system could be mounted with `nosuid` option.

From mount man page

> nosuid: Do not allow set-user-identifier or set-group-identifier bits
>   to take effect.